# Create and Search BST from a txt file

Tags: java, parsing, binary-search-tree, filereader

I am currently in an intro data structures class and am really struggling with one of our problems about Binary Search Trees. This is the first time I have implemented this data structure and am doing my best to learn it.

Problem:
The program is supposed to create and search a BST of name and occurrence data, based upon the census data of babies born that year. We are given this data in a txt file.

I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out why it is not working. I am really just looking for someone to lead me in the right direction from here and give me some good feedback on what I already have because I feel really lost! My current work is below. I am implementing this in java. Thanks in advance!

```
public class Node {
String name; 
int data;

Node leftChild;
Node rightChild; 

public Node (String n, int d) {
    name = n;
    data = d;
}


public class BinarySearchTree` {

public static Node root;

public void addNode(String name, int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(name, data);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node focusNode = root;

        Node parent; 

        while(true) {
            parent = focusNode;
            if (name.compareTo(focusNode.name) < 0) {   
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild; 
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                } else {
                    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                    if (focusNode == null) { 
                        parent.rightChild = newNode; 
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public Node searchName(String name) {
    Node focusNode = root;

    while (!focusNode.name.equals(name)) {
        if (name.compareTo(focusNode.name) < 0) {
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
        } else {
            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
        }
        if (focusNode == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return focusNode;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

    FileReader file = new FileReader("/Users/mattspahr/Desktop/test.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String  str = null, 
            name = null, 
            num = null;

    int     data;

    while(reader.readLine() != null) {
        str = reader.readLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '0' || c <= '9') {
                name = str.substring(0, i);
            }
            num = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]" , "");
        }

        data = Integer.parseInt(num);

        tree.addNode(name,data);

        Node n = tree.searchName("Buffy  ");

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to say how it is not working as well. Expand a bit on how you tried it, what is your expected output and what did you get.

Comment: From a quick glance, you are not using the 'data' field

Comment: IMHO, a BST is something you either implement recursively or with an array. Have you thought about using a recursive insert?